# browsers won't display JSON content automatically

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, json

My PHP (SLIM framework) is generating a JSON file. I have checked the file on JSON validator and everything is fine. When I enter `index.html`, my local, AngularJS main file, on the browser it does not display the JSON file automatically but asks me whether to open/save the file. I'm using Apache virtual host, MySQL, from Xampp. I want the browser to display the JSON without saving the file locally, so that, when I finish the project and attach it to a domain, anybody will be able to display the JSON content on his computer.

This is the php file:

```
`<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

// Get All Customers
$app->get('/api/calendar', function (Request $request, Response $response) {

    // echo 'CALENDAR'; });

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM days";

    try {
    // Get DB Object
    $dbcalendar = new dbcalendar();
    //Connect
    $dbcalendar = $dbcalendar->connect();

    $stmt = $dbcalendar->query($sql);
    $dbcalendar = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    // $dbcalendar = null;

    return $response->withJson($dbcalendar);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $error = array('error' => array('text' => $e->getMessage()));
        return $response->withJson($error,500);
    }
});`
```

OK. I have changed the php file (I hope correctly) according to Fred suggestion:

```
`<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

// Get All Customers
$app->get('/api/calendar', function (Request $request, Response $response) {

    // echo 'CALENDAR'; });

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM days";

    try {
    // Get DB Object
    $dbcalendar = new dbcalendar();
    //Connect
    $dbcalendar = $dbcalendar->connect();

    $stmt = $dbcalendar->query($sql);
    $dbcalendar = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    // $dbcalendar = null;

    return $response->withJson($dbcalendar);
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $error = array('error' => array('text' => $e->getMessage()));
        return $response->withJson($error,500);
    }
});`
```

but there still isn't any change.

Comment: please submit some code

Comment: Are you sending the correct accept and content-type headers to the browser for a json file? (hint: application/json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you output your JSON string, set the header, like this:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

That should tell the browser to expect JSON content.

Comment: It works now. I have added the following two lines of code at the very beginning of my php file: `<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");`

Answer (score 0):

as @RichardAtHome said check you content type in http header and if it is ok then . 
you can use JSON.stringify() and then output it as normal string or do some formating .
if this is not case then explain your problem with some code and output screenshot too.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp